# Iterating through an array in Angular Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am currently trying to iterate through an array using *ngFor but nothing shows up on the page. This is the code for the HTML

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Recent News
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
      <ion-card *ngFor="let article of articles">
        <ion-card-content>
          <h2>{{article.title}}</h2>
          <p>{{article.description}}</p>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <p>Powered by NEWS API</p>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

The following is the code from the .ts (typescript?)

```
 getNews() {
    this.rest.getNews()
    .then(result => {
      this.news = result;
      console.log(this.news);
    });
  }
```

The console log of `this.news` is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofHaK.jpg). However, if I `console.log(this.news.articles[0])`, [this is the output instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Kxjh.jpg).

Could it be done such that I iterate through from 0 to 9 instead of using ngFor or am I missing something?

**EDIT:**
home.ts as follows

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { RestProvider } from '../../providers/rest/rest';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  news: any;
  errorMessage: string;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public rest:RestProvider) {
    this.getNews();
  }

  getNews() {
    this.rest.getNews()
    .then(result => {
      this.news = result;
      console.log(this.news.articles[0]);
    });
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take another variable called `articels`

```
  getNews() {
    this.rest.getNews()
    .then(result => {
      this.news = result;
      this.articels = this.news.articles;
      console.log(this.news);
      console.log(this.articels);
    });
  }
```

with this your html should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the articles in `ngFor` with news. The data you want to display is in news array:

```
<ion-content padding>
      <ion-card *ngFor="let article of news.articles">
        <ion-card-content>
          <h2>{{article.title}}</h2>
          <p>{{article.description}}</p>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: I get this error after doing this 
`ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

Comment: It gives this error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'article' of undefined`.

Comment: @ZivOfir articles not article

Comment: I'm guessing it don't work due to my variable news being `any`. I edited the OP to include the whole home.ts, could you help me see if I did anything wrong there?